# How to set HTML5 Form min restriction for datepicker to "Check-In Date (user input)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

What do I need to add for the min restriction to make sure the user-input for check-out date is after the user-input for check-in date?

```html
<form>
  Enter Check-In Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="checkin"><br>
  
  Enter Check-Out Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="checkout"><br>
</form>
```

Can this be done with just HTML5 or does it need to include javascript?

Comment: Try this https://tiffanybbrown.com/2013/10/24/date-input-in-html5-restricting-dates-and-thought-for-working-around-limitations/ May be it helps you out

Comment: you need to use javascript/jQuery to do that validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

java script need for validation .Compare the `check in` date is less the `check out` date

```js
function check() {
  if(document.getElementById('checkin').value < document.getElementById('checkout').value)
    { console.log('ok')}
  else{
    console.log('Not allowed')
    }
  
  }
```

```html
<form>
      Enter Check-In Date:<br>
      <input type="date" id="checkin" name="checkin"><br>
      Enter Check-Out Date:<br>
      <input type="date" id="checkout" name="checkout" onchange="check()"><br>
    </form>
```

Comment: i think that's not what OP asked you to do .

Comment: @Mahi for why ?.Its will restricted the date to below check in date

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was looking for. I just want it so the user cannot put a Check-out date that is before Check-in date.

Comment: @prasad i have added my answer. i thought OP wanted that

Answer (score 0):

You can use min and max attributes of HTML5 input date

```
<form>
  Enter Check-In Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="checkin" max="2016-11-06"><br>

  Enter Check-Out Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="checkout" min="2016-11-07"><br>
</form>
```

Where date of max in "checkin" is smaller than date of min in "checkout".

Or try validation in javascript.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want static dates. I want to set the min for Check-out Date to be whatever the user inputs for Check-in Date.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("2").disabled = true;
$("#1").on("change paste keyup", function() {
   console.log($(this).val()); 
  var testDate= $(this).val();
  var date_regex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
  if((date_regex.test(testDate)))
   document.getElementById("2").disabled = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Enter Check-In Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="checkin" id="1"><br>
  
  Enter Check-Out Date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="checkout" id="2"><br>
</form>
```